# Browser rendered code instead of page

Tags: html, asp.net, iis, error-handling

I Hosted *.Net application* in Local IIS Server. I did't manage error case in ***MVC***. I used IIS .NET Error for page redirection for particular page.

ASP.Net error page display error
page in `Edge` but 
`Chrome` and `Firefox` display
content instead of page.

My procedure are as follow:

1. Internet information services (IIS) Manager
2. mysite> Asp.NET> .Net Error Page
   [image: .NET Error Setting]

and content inside `Error.html`

```html
<html>
<head>
Coming Soon
</head>
<body>
<h1>Page Under Construction</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it required page redirection handling in **MVC**?

Comment: Instead of handling errors in IIS why dont you handle them in the web.config file without disturbing the current code?.

Comment: ISS errors handling also write needful configuration in web.config automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how you call redirecting page.

Try this(MVC form of Code):

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
    return View("~/Views/error.cshtml");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow below steps in order to redirect the error pages in MVC.Please note no need to configure anything in IIS server.

**Step 1**: Create a blank asp.net mvc 4 application.

**Step 2**: Add a HomeController. Copy and paste the following code.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    throw new Exception("Something went wrong");
}
```

**Step 3:** Enable custom errors in web.config file, that is present in the root directory of your mvc application. "customErrors" element must be nested under "".

```
<customErrors mode="On">
</customErrors>
```

**Step 4:** Add "Shared" folder under "Views" folder. Add Error.cshtml view inside this folder.

For more detailed explanation,follow the link http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.in/2013/08/part-72-handleerror-attribute-in-mvc.html